# (Python Numpy) Are there cases where assignment operators (eg. *=) work but the long hand versions don't?

Tags: python, numpy, matrix, operators

I'm multiplying two matrices A and B of the same size, elementwise. I get a 'shapes not aligned' error thrown when I use the following code:

```
    A = A*B
```

However the following code works correctly:

```
    A *= B
```

Are these different? Are there cases where the second one can work and the first can't?  I'm really confused as I thought they did the same thing.

Comment: You *must* provide a [mcve]. The first is equivalent to `A = A.__mul__(B)` the other is equivalent to `A = A.__imul__(B)`. They aren't equivalent, but it is impossible to say anything other than pure speculation without more details.

Comment: Why are they not equivalent? Could you point me to an explanation? I've added an answer below. A is an nd-array of shape (5,1000) and B is a matrix of the same size.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes. Inplace operators use different [dunders](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/datamodel.html#special-method-names) than [standard operators](https://docs.python.org/3/library/operator.html#module-operator). In order to use [inplace operators](https://docs.python.org/3/library/operator.html#in-place-operators), e.g. `*=` the `__imul__` method must be defined for the instance with the argument. In contrast, the `*` operator uses the instance's `__mul__` method.

Comment: But which `__mul__` is being used in `A*B`?  The element-wise for `A`, or matrix-multiplication for `B`?

Comment: `A * B` results in `A.__mul__(B)`, `A *= B` results in `A.__imul__(B)`. It is always the left-hand-side's method which is used. In this case, `A` must define `__mul__` or `__imul__` for an argument of `B`'s type.

Comment: In OP's case, `B` is `np.matrix`, which has a higher `__array_priority__`.  B's `__mul__` (or `__rmul__`) is `np.dot`, which is what gives the `not aligned` error.

Answer (score 1):

The error was coming from the fact that A was an nd-array and B was was of type 'matrix'.

Using:

```
A = A * np.asarray(B)
```

to convert the matrix worked.

I'd still like to know the reason that one worked and the other didn't!

Comment: The full error message and traceback for `A*B` gives clues as to why it doesn't work.

Answer (score 1):

If, as you noticed in the answer, one array is `np.matrix`:

```
In [52]: A = np.ones((1,3)); B = np.matrix([1,2,3])
In [53]: A
Out[53]: array([[1., 1., 1.]])
In [54]: B
Out[54]: matrix([[1, 2, 3]])
```

These have the same shape.  But `*` for `B` is matrix multiplication.

```
In [55]: A*B
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<ipython-input-55-47896efed660>", line 1, in <module>
    A*B
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/dist-packages/numpy/matrixlib/defmatrix.py", line 224, 
 in __rmul__
    return N.dot(other, self)
  File "<__array_function__ internals>", line 5, in dot
ValueError: shapes (1,3) and (1,3) not aligned: 3 (dim 1) != 1 (dim 0)
```

Note that `A*B` becomes `B.__rmul__(A)`, which in turn is evaluated as `np.dot(A,B)`.

`dot` for (1,3) with (3,1) results in a (1,1) inner product.  Note also that the result is `np.matrix`.

```
In [56]: A*B.T
Out[56]: matrix([[6.]])
```

In `*=` `A's` multiplication rules:

```
In [57]: A *=B
In [58]: A
Out[58]: array([[1., 2., 3.]])
```

`@` is the matrix multiplication operator:

```
In [59]: A@B
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<ipython-input-59-5016aafd2858>", line 1, in <module>
    A@B
ValueError: matmul: Input operand 1 has a mismatch in its core dimension 0, with gufunc signature (n?,k),(k,m?)->(n?,m?) (size 1 is different from 3)

In [60]: A@B.T
Out[60]: matrix([[14.]])
```

Converting `B` to np.array:

```
In [61]: B.A
Out[61]: array([[1, 2, 3]])
In [62]: A@(B.T).A
Out[62]: array([[14.]])
```

Look at the `np.matrix` docs.

Why did `A*B` use `B's` multiplication definition instead of `A's`? Because `matrix` has a higher priority:

```
In [63]: B.__array_priority__
Out[63]: 10.0
In [64]: A.__array_priority__
Out[64]: 0.0
```

Note what happens when `B` is on the right:

```
In [70]: B *= A
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<ipython-input-70-50eabec4c4f6>", line 1, in <module>
    B *= A
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/dist-packages/numpy/matrixlib/defmatrix.py", line 227, in __imul__
    self[:] = self * other
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/dist-packages/numpy/matrixlib/defmatrix.py", line 218, in __mul__
    return N.dot(self, asmatrix(other))
  File "<__array_function__ internals>", line 5, in dot
ValueError: shapes (1,3) and (1,3) not aligned: 3 (dim 1) != 1 (dim 0)

In [71]: B *= A.T
In [72]: B
Out[72]: matrix([[14, 14, 14]])
```

---

Even when `np.matrix` is not a factor, `A*=...` will be different in  that `A's` shape and dtype cannot change.  `A=A*` makes a new array, which may have a different shape or dtype.

For example `Out[72]` is int dtype, just like the original `B`.  `Out[58]` is float, like the original `A`.

---

Because of the priority, `A*B` is evaluated as `B.__rmul__(A)`.  Compare this code with the traceback for `In[55]`:

```
Signature: B.__rmul__(other)
Docstring: Return value*self.
Source:   
    def __rmul__(self, other):
        return N.dot(other, self)
```